# SignalR 1.2.2 Works in IE8 and Chrome 45 but fails in IE9 and FF 34

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR 1.2.2, .NET 4.0, IIS Express (under development).

This is strange as usually things don't work in IE but work in other browsers. As this works in some browsers I am assuming it is a client and JS issue. I have the following code:

```
<script src="/scripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/respond.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
$(function () {
    var info = $.connection.infoHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    info.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (timestamp, status, message) {
        appendToLog(timestamp, status, message);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
        $("#connectionId").val(connectionId);
    });
});
```

I get no notification in IE9/FF34 but works as expected in IE8/Chrome45.
I enabled CORS support. I added JSON2.js. I am still having the same problem.
On FF I am getting this error:

```
The connection to http://localhost:6677/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=Z2mxweQj-PocYsBHebUD4vqsBpBOVfU3vPZOEX5W09dampCExo-emJbYGe_gCz7iFN_tuHlnTjgUUeKz1ZXlcySsWQSOzaHQS8SE3N9Q_MzfUjSzr18mKOOqnk_lVtjdHi4LOmTbsN4q5tgXdZc_p15Ncq_cIgkwEyJoJoApXjbMB6k6vXwe_zQ5Aa_pB5iP0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22infohub%22%7D%5D&tid=6 was interrupted while the page was loading.
[16:11:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = false.
jquery.....min.js (line 10)
[16:11:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.
```

I am getting this **while** uploading a file to the server via full post (while the thread is still running before a page refresh).

> Any ideas how I should progress in investigating this or a solution?

Comment: Try pasting that connect url into Firefox and see what it says? (the token has a tine limit and embeds the username so generate a fresh url)